# Very poor performance when streaming through VLC "sout"

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vlc, raspberry-pi4

My goal is to stream a USB-Webcam from a Raspberry using VLC. The generated stream should be able to be shown using simple HTML visible on the most popular browsers.

So I use a simple ""-object in my HTML:

```
<video id="video" src="http://quarkcam:8080" autoplay="true" width="800" height="600" controls>/video>
```

The vlc-Command to create the Stream is the following: (using OGG which seemed to be the right choice for compatibility (feel free to correct me on this))

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :v4l2-width=800 :v4l2-height=600 :live-caching=100 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=4410,scodec=none,fps=15}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8080/}" :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

While this works technically I have to reduce the resolution to 800x600 and framerate to 15fps on a Raspberry Pi 4 to make this work without constantly buffering. (theoretical maximum from webcam: 30fps on 1600x1200)

Are there better options for `vcodec` Codecs that can be used that would provide a stream that better fits to the Pi's hardware capabilities and STILL can be simply included into am HTML-page? I do NOT need to get the maximum available from the hardware but would at least be able to have a stable 30fps stream.

Comment: Slip into the raspberry pi forums...

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 4, while much powerful than previous iterations, is still not capable of decoding video and parallelly stream it, at least on the default Pi OS.

I suggest you to use MotionEyeOS - https://github.com/motioneye-project/motioneyeos. It is supposed to work on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS kernel: 4.19 (raspbian)

https://github.com/motioneye-project/motioneyeos/wiki/Installation

A well documented tutorial is given here: [https://randomnerdtutorials.com/install-motioneyeos-on-raspberry-pi-surveillance-camera-system/#:~:text=What%20is%20MotionEyeOS%3F,Raspberry%20Pi%20(all%20versions)%3B](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/install-motioneyeos-on-raspberry-pi-surveillance-camera-system/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20MotionEyeOS%3F,Raspberry%20Pi%20(all%20versions)%3B)

Thank You,
Have a Great Day
Naveen